# Find all possible solutions to how many people voted on a quiz

Tags: linear-algebra, percentages

Imagine that there's a quiz on a website and I am only able to know the percentage results. How can I predict all possible solutions to how many people voted?

For example:

```
Quiz 1:

Candidate A: 33,33% votes

Candidate B: 33,33% votes

Candidate C: 33,33% votes
```

It's easy to see that 3 or 6 or 9 or (multiple of 3) people voted.

But what about Quiz 2:

```
Candidate A: 34,09% votes

Candidate B: 52,76% votes

Candidate C: 13,15% votes
```

How can I predict possible solutions? How to deal with aproximation/truncation of the percentages?

I want to know a general solution, not a solution for my Quiz 2.

Thanks

Comment: [Continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) give you a good way to find rational approximations with small denominators.

Comment: There's a huge problem: If you come up with a number of voters, any integer multiple is also a solution. Therefore, it's an understatement to say that there is no accurate way to determine the number of voters ...

Comment: @MattiP.  True, but there is still a good question here.  It comes up, say, when looking at batting averages.  We know a hitters average is rounded and that the true denominator is (more or less) the number of times they have been at bat.  We know a lot about what that number is (it's easy to estimate it, say).